# Why is the composer command not found?

Tags: php, .htaccess, centos, composer-php

Why is the composer instruction from README, is failing when i apply as below?

[image]

Tried as below but failing:

```
# uname -a
Linux signal 3.10.0-123.8.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 22 19:06:58 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# php --version
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Oct 31 2014 12:59:36) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

# ls
LICENSE    bootstrap.php  detect.php  index.php
README.md  composer.json  hooks       templates

# composer create-project whichbrowser/server .
-bash: composer: command not found

# php composer create-project whichbrowser/server .
Could not open input file: composer
```

**EDIT:**

```
[root@signal wb]# php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
Installer verified
[root@signal wb]# php composer-setup.php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading 1.2.1...

Composer successfully installed to: /var/www/html/sip-phone/tls/website/wb/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
[root@signal wb]# php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"    
[root@signal wb]# php composer.phar create-project whichbrowser/server .
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Installing whichbrowser/server (v2.0.12)


  [InvalidArgumentException]          
  Project directory ./ is not empty.  


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<version>]

[root@signal wb]#
```

Comment: Have you installed composer? It's not part of the PHP distribution, so you'll have to install it from https://getcomposer.org/ (and it's usually named composer.phar, if you haven't renamed it yourself)

Comment: I used Zend framework, where i use composer yes. but in this case its not working.

Comment: Well, the composer binary can't be found, so it's not installed (or not on your path). Are you on the same computer / vm / image / container as you usually are? Do you have a composer.phar in the current directory? Do `which composer` give you any useful information?

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23410867/ - please see its installed but still failing.

Comment: That's a different error. And `Project directory ./ is not empty.` is pretty clear

Comment: Please see my EDIT Section, composer is installed but failing.

Comment: `php composer.phar create-project whichbrowser/server this_arg_is_the_path_of_an_empty_directory`

Comment: As it says, your project directory is not empty. Probably because that's where you just downloaded and installed composer. And don't run composer as root. Let create-project create a new directory for the project.

Comment: Thank you, its working by creating `mkdir /root/emptydirectory` and then by applying`php composer.phar create-project whichbrowser/server /root/emptydirectory` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not installed composer, please install it:

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('SHA384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e115a8dc7871f15d853148a7fbac7da27d6c0030b848d9b3dc09e2a0388afed865e6a3d6b3c0fad45c48e2b5fc1196ae') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

EDIT:

Read how to install: https://getcomposer.org/download/

you create project whichbrowser/server at non empty directory, try create project at empty directory:

```
mkdir ./myproject
php composer.phar create-project whichbrowser/server ./myproject
```

Comment: Can you edit and explain why your code works and what your code actually does, this will help everyone reading this to know what's going on. Cheers :)

Comment: @Hardy Rust: please see my EDIT section, its not working.

Comment: The code of this answer will be incorrect on the next release of composer.  You should just post a link to https://getcomposer.org/download/ instead.

Comment: NOT working i get following `# php composer.phar require whichbrowser/parser
Could not open input file: composer.phar`

Comment: yum install php-mbstring